# CachingConnectionFactory based pubishing is failing sometimes with errror as Connection has been terminated by the server

Tags: spring-boot, publish-subscribe, spring-jms, tibco-ems

I am getting the below exception sometimes when posting message to a queue. I am using the JMS template and CachingConnectionFactory with spring boot. In the documentation of CachingConnectionFactory, I can see that session need to be closed. But as I am using the JMS template, not understanding how to close the session. Is that causing the issue. The error is not happening always and the failure is random in behavior. Please help with your suggestion

```
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Connection has been terminated by the server
    at com.tibco.tibjms.Tibjmsx.buildException(Tibjmsx.java:676)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp._confirmTransacted(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:3576)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp._confirm(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:3982)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp._commit(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:3211)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp.commit(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:5374)
    at com.fedex.mi.decorator.jms.FedexJmsSession.commit(FedexJmsSession.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedSessionInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:383)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130.commit(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.commitIfNecessary(JmsUtils.java:218)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:612)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.lambda$send$3(JmsTemplate.java:586)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:504)
    ... 68 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the exception related to not closing connection. Most likely TibcoEMS server was not available for some reason or connection terminated by some network issue.

You need to define **reconnectOnException** settings in you CachingConnectionFactory definition to reconnect automatically if you don't have it already.

something like:

```
<bean id="tibcoConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="tibcoServerJndiObjectFactoryBean"/>
    <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true"/>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="100"/>
    <property name="cacheConsumers" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

You may also need to define QueueConnectionFactory fault-tolerant failover settings on TibcoEMS side

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/ems/8.5.1/doc/html/GUID-270D7C10-7686-44B0-BC11-D7BFF1F33A7E.html